# how to display data in column as row wise in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are 2 tables Employee and Timing
input is

```
EMPCODE LOGIN LOGOUT TRANSDATE
1001    9.30   17.30  20/01/2014
1002    1.30   22.30  20/01/2014


EXPECTED OUTPUT 

**EMPCODE  INOUT(Login/Logout)       TRANSDATE**
1001           9.30               20/01/2014
1001           17.30              20/01/2014
1002           10.30              21/01/2014
1002           22.30              21/01/2014

Please provide sql code?
```

Comment: You probably want to use a UNION statement. Show us what you've tried already, and we can help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CROSS APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to unpivot the columns:

```
SELECT  T.EmpCode, i.InOut, T.TransDate
FROM    Timing T
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES (T.Login), (T.Logout)) i (InOut);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e71b/1)**

You could also use [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  upvt.EmpCode, upvt.InOut, upvt.TransDate
FROM    Timing T
        UNPIVOT
        (   InOut
            FOR [Type] IN (Login, Logout)
        ) upvt;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e71b/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
  Select Empcode,[InOUT],[TRANSDATE]
  from 
  (
   Select EmpCode, Login as  [INOUT] ,[TRANSDATE]
   from Table1
   union all
   Select EmpCode, Logout as  [INOUT] ,[TRANSDATE]
   from Table1
  )a
  order by empcode
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbcbe2/1)